# Confusion in understanding the definition of group actions

Tags: group-theory, definition, group-actions

I was studying about "group actions" in group theory. The definition of a  group action is given as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a non-empty set . A **(left) action** of $G$ on $S$ is a function $\cdot :G\times S\longrightarrow S$(usually denoted by $\cdot(g,x)\longrightarrow g\cdot x$) such that
>
> i) $(g_1g_2)\cdot x=g_1\cdot (g_2\cdot x)$ and
>
> ii. $e\cdot x=x$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$
>
> for all $x\in S,g_1,g_2\in G$. (Note: If no confusion arises then we write $gx$ for $g\cdot x$)

However, I don't get this definition at all. First of all, if we assume $G=\{g_1,g_2,g_3,\dots \}$ and $S=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$, then $G\times S=\{(g_1,x_1),(g_2,x_2),(g_3,x_3),\dots\}$. Now, if we replace $\cdot$ by $f$ (in order to make the notations simple), then we have $f:G\times S\longrightarrow S$. Also, it is given that this $f:G\times S\longrightarrow S$ notation is usually denoted by $f(g,x)\longrightarrow gfx(=gf(x))$; thus, $f(g,x)\longrightarrow gf(x)$. Now, the definition stated two conditions: $(g_1g_2)f(x)=g_1f(g_2f(x))$ and $ef(x)=x$.

Now, first off if we consider $f(g,x)$, then its obviously a "two-variable" function, so what's the significance of $gf(x)$ in "$f(g,x)\longrightarrow gf(x)$"? Also, how do they conclude $gf(x)\in S$ (as the range of $f$ is $S$)? Also, what is meant by the conditions?

The domain of the function $f$ is $G\times S$ so writing "$g_1g_2f(x)$" and "$ef(x)$" makes no sense at all *i.e.* the function must take two variables as an input but clearly it's not the case here. I am not quite getting it . . .

I tried searching if there were any posts made previously on this site that answers my questions about this particular topic but I couldn't find any . . .

Comment: What do you mean by $gf(x)$? Your $f$ needs two arguments, so this doesn’t make sense. It is just a 2-variable map $\cdot(g,x)$ which we denote $g\cdot x$ in order to make it look like an action/multiplication for a lighter notation.

Comment: @T.P. Actually, that's what my question is, I simply replaced the function "$\cdot$" by $f$ as mentioned in my post. Similarly, $g.x=gf(x)$ also makes no sense...

Comment: @T.P. I just changed the notation and nothing else...

Comment: "$f(g,x)$" is the same as "$\cdot(g,x)$", but this latter allows the more friendly infix notation "$g\cdot x$". All these represent the same image element in $S$.

Comment: @Devo Ok! If I get this correctly, does this mean $\cdot$ or $f$ whatever way one denotes it (here) , it is just a binary operation just like (say for example) $+(\text{addition})$, etc, i.e the function $\cdot$ takes two element as input and maps it to an element in $S$ performing an operation upon the two variables of input say $a\lambda x$ such that if $x_1=a\lambda x$, then $x_1\in S$(and $a\in G,x\in S$), and then, $\cdot$ is defined by $\cdot(a,x)=a\lambda x=x_1=a.x$ , right?...

Comment: Right, @Franklin

Comment: @Devo So it's all a confusion of notations. One can easily define the function $\cdot :G\times S\longrightarrow S$ as $\cdot(g_1,s_1)=g_1\lambda s_1=s_2$, where $g_1\in G$ and $s_1,s_2\in S$. It causes less confusion but if one denotes the operation as $c.x$ instead of  $c\lambda x$, it becomes much confusing as we are generally not used to seeing two variable  functions as infix functions, i.e becomes much better if we use a different infix symbol to denote this binary operation (leaving aside $+,-,×,$, etc which we use in our daily lives) . What do you think ?...Thank you!...

Comment: Well, I think that precisely the weird (though correct, in infix notation) "$gfx$" has led you to the nonsensical "$gf(x)$" etc. So, given that the infix notation is handy to dealing with action's defining properties, I'd definitely prefer "$g\cdot x$" (likewise the usual "$x+y$").

Comment: @Devo Thank you! So the main takeaway from here is that, one can write a two variable function $f:G×S\longrightarrow S$, in an infix notation if one wishes to be ?...

Comment: Yes, and this is a case where the infix notation (with the "$\cdot$", for example) is really beneficial (try to write action's properties in the "standard", non-infix notation like "$\cdot(g,x)$"...).

Comment: @Devo Thanks a lot! I do get it now...

Comment: @Devo Just one more thing: in the condition $(i)$ $(g_1g_2).x=g_1.(g_2.x)$, in the part $(g_1g_2).x$, that $g_1g_2$, is performed with respect to  the $group \space operation  $ associated with $G$. If the $group \space operation  $ associated with $G$ is $*$, then $g_1g_2=g_1*g_2$, such that ,  the $(i)$ $(g_1g_2).x=(g_1*g_2).x=g_1.(g_2.x)$, correct?...

Comment: Your description of $G\times S$ is very  misleading. Note that you only list pairs of the form $(g_i,s_i)$, with the same index for both elements, when in reality the set $G\times S$ contains all pairs of the form $(g_i,s_j)$ with $i$ and $j$ arbitrary and not necessarily distinct. So $G\times S = \{(g_1,s_1), (g_1,s_2),\ldots, (g_2,s_1),(g_2,s_2),(g_2,s_3),\ldots,(g_n,s_1),(g_n,s_2),\ldots\}$....

Comment: The notation "$gf(x)$" is *very bad*. Following usual reading, it would be interpreted as a function whose only argument is $x$, evaluated and then left-multiplied by $g$ in some way. That does not make the notation "simple", as you claim, but instead makes it more prone to confusion. It would be like writing $af(b)$ instead of $a+b$.

Comment: "We generally are not used to seeing two variable functions as infix functions". Actually, we do it all the time. That's what we do with addition, subtraction, multiplication, division; it is also what we do with scalar multiplication in vector spaces, which is an example where the two arguments come from different sets.